# An integral domain R such that every non-zero prime ideal of R[X] is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, problem-solving

The following question was asked in my abstract algebra quiz and I had no idea on how to solve it .

> Question: Let R be an integral domain such that every non-zero prime ideal of R[X] (where R is an indeterminate) is maximal . Choose the correct option(s) :

1. R is a field
2. R contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring
3. Every ideal in R[X] is principal
4. R contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a subring for some prime number p.

Answer :

> A, C

I am absolutely clueless on how I should I contract option or how to prove any of them . I tried it 10 days earlier also and there was nothing which I can think of . So , its my humble request to all to please tell me on how to approach this question .

Thanks!!

Comment: If you know that $k[X]$ has this property for every field $k$, that allows you to rule out 2 and 4 immediately, since you can choose any $k$ you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if $R$ is an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic, then it is clearly true. This rules out 2 and 4.

1 implies 3, because the ring of polynomials over a field is PID.

If $R$ is not a field, then it has a nonzero proper prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak p[x]$ is a prime in $R[x]$, but not maximal.

Comment: can you please give  a proof of line 1 of your answer?

Comment: @User: A polynomial ring over a field is Noetherian and Euclidean. This implies that if $R$ is a field, then prime ideals in $R[X]$ are the principal ideals generated by irreducible polynomials. If $R$ is algebraically closed, then the only irreducible polynomials are linear, so they obviously generate maximal ideals. This is also true if $R$ is not algebraically closed (that the ideals generated by irreducible polynomials are maximal), but it is not completely obvious in that case.

Comment: Thanks !! everything in your answer is clear except the fact that how does iff R is an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic, then 2, and 4 are ruled out ? Can you please also explain that.

Comment: @User: Simply because there are algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero (so not containing any finite field) and of positive characteristic (so not containing the integers).